# Spring/Thymeleaf - is it possible to intercept a controller response before the Thymeleaf engine kicks in, and bypass Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Spring version: 4.1.6, Thymeleaf version: 3.0.0

Essentially, in certain scenarios, I want to render HTML using something other than Thymeleaf. So if my controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/","/index"}, method={RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
public String renderIndexForCompanyUser(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("someKey", "someValue");
    return "index";
}
```

I want an interceptor, or something similar, that can do:

```
//pseudocode
public void intercept(Response response){
    boolean someCondition = ...
    if(someCondition){
        renderHTMLWithoutThymeleaf(response.getTemplateName(), response.getModel());
        // Thymeleaf rendering gets skipped in this scenario
    }
    else {
        // render via Thymeleaf as normal
    }
}
```

Is something like this possible? I'm finding documentation on the HandlerInterceptor interface, but I'm not sure how to get Spring to skip Thymeleaf in certain scenarios

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about the scenario? Understanding why exactly you want this might lead to alternatives that are maybe easier to implement.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe We're deprecating Thymeleaf, but management requires the deprecation to be feature flagged -- so essentially we need the ability to toggle between Thymeleaf and our alternative dynamically at runtime, without a service restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view name interpretation is handled by `ViewResoler`'s. Spring creates some of them by default and other ones are added to the application context by project dependencies. This is the case with Thymeleaf - it autoconfigures a `ThymeleafViewResolver` which in fact has some useful properties to control which views will be rendered by it:

`spring.thymeleaf.view-names` - Comma-separated list of view names (patterns allowed) that can be resolved.
`spring.thymeleaf.excluded-view-names` - Comma-separated list of view names (patterns allowed) that should be excluded from resolution.
`spring.thymeleaf.prefix` - Prefix that gets prepended to view names when building a URL, e.g. `classpath:/templates/`
`spring.thymeleaf.suffix` - Suffix that gets appended to view names when building a URL, e.g. `.html`

Having configured the views that will be handled specifically by Thymeleaf you can then return either those or the ones handled by another view resolver based on the condition in your controller.